# getting rid of 'NONE' before a print statement in python

Tags: python, printing, output

Hi I am new to python and programming, I have written some code for a wordgame and when it runs, 
there is a 'None' printed out before some output. is there a way to remove them, I know it has to do with the loop returning nothing but I would rather not have to change the code a lot if possible(took me long enough the first time :))
Thanks in advance.

```
def compPlayHand(hand, wordList, n):

    #  Keep track of the total score
    totalScore = 0
    # As long as there are still usable letters left in the hand:
    while compChooseWord(hand,wordList,n) is not None:

        # Display the hand

        print "Current Hand: ",
        print  displayHand(hand),

        word = compChooseWord(hand,wordList,n)  # comp chooses word
        hand = updateHand(hand,word)
        # Tell the user how many points the word earned, and the updated total score, in one line followed by a blank line
        getWordScore(word,n)
        totalScore += getWordScore(word,n)
        # Update the hand
        c = calculateHandlen(hand)

        print   '"'+str(word)+'"' + " earned " + str(getWordScore(word,n)) +' points.' " Total:  " + str(totalScore) + " points."     # Otherwise (the word is valid):
        print

        if compChooseWord(hand,wordList,n) is None:  # End the game (break out of the loop)

            print  "Current Hand: ", \
                displayHand(hand),
            print "Total score: " + str(totalScore) + " points."
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We've been over this, don't `print displayHand`, just call it on its own.

```
def compPlayHand(hand, wordList, n):
    #  Keep track of the total score
    totalScore = 0
    # As long as there are still usable letters left in the hand:
    while compChooseWord(hand,wordList,n) is not None:

        # Display the hand

        print "Current Hand: ",
        displayHand(hand)

        word = compChooseWord(hand,wordList,n)  # comp chooses word
        hand = updateHand(hand,word)
        # Tell the user how many points the word earned, and the updated total score, in one line followed by a blank line
        getWordScore(word,n)
        totalScore += getWordScore(word,n)
        # Update the hand
        c = calculateHandlen(hand)

        print   '"'+str(word)+'"' + " earned " + str(getWordScore(word,n)) +' points.' " Total:  " + str(totalScore) + " points."     # Otherwise (the word is valid):
        print

        if compChooseWord(hand,wordList,n) is None:  # End the game (break out of the loop)

            print  "Current Hand: ",
            displayHand(hand)

            print "Total score: " + str(totalScore) + " points."
```

Comment: Thanks! I feel pretty dumb after that.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham If this answers your question, feel free to select it as the correct answer by clicking the green checkmark.